# Why is reading from a file not working after using a function?

Tags: python

My code is supposed to find the occurrence of words in a text. For some reason, after using this function, the reading method from this specific text[won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkEVb.png)(empty lists for .readlines() method and nothing for .read()). The code is:

```
def counter(new):
    words = dict()
    lines=new.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        text=line.split()
        for word in text:
            if word not in words:
                words[word]=1
            else: words[word]+=1
    return [tuple(x) for x in words.items()]
```

I haven't found any mistake that can cause this.

Comment: "won't work" is not a very descriptive problem description. Please clarify. Provide a [mcve] that others can see.

Comment: If you expect to read from `new` after calling that function, you're out of luck, since you've already read the whole thing. If you want to read it again for some reason, you'll need to "rewind" it with the `.seek` method.

Comment: Please show the code which does not behave as expected (and please state what you expected and how it behaved). This code does not do anything until it is called, and then what it does depends on what the argument is. What does not work after that is absolutely impossible to know without more info.

Comment: @PM2Ring or perhaps more sanely, simply open a new file-object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `.seek` is much cheaper than closing & reopening the file.

Comment: @PM2Ring sure, but manually seeking around files, in my experience, can be tricky if you aren't careful. Unless I'm trying to optimize something, I will pretty much always just open a new file-object.

Comment: Access to  *words* dictionary can be considerably simplified by using a `defaultdict` from `collections` module: `words = defaultdict(lambda: 0)` gets rid of the if.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming `new` is the result of calling `open(..)`, which should be a file handle that you are passing into the function. Calling `readlines()` is exhausting it, so trying to read from the file using the same handle won't work. Either open a new handle, or you can call `new.seek(0)` (better option than opening a completely new handle - although there are some cases where the same handle will be returned again, but lets not dive too deep into that here) to move the index to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Now I understand my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't use `lines=new.readlines()` followed by `for line in lines:`. Just use `for line in new:`.

Comment: @Matthias agreed -- not a lot to gain by storing into list, better to just iterate over it. Also, if you think about it, re-reading the file lines over and over doesn't make a great deal of sense either (storing it somewhere seems better); but maybe OP has some other requirement.